# How to search for a concept/class using owlready2?

Tags: python, owl, ontology, taxonomy, owlready

I have a taxonomy as shown in the figure. I want to perform a search for "TomatoTopping" and get its ancestors. How do I do it using python(owlready) ?
[image]

Comment: just iterate all classes and check if the label or the local name of the URI matches

Comment: Is it possible to search only the first level of classes since I could have large number of classes ? For example , I want to search only the subclasses of the root ("Thing"). i.e  Pizza & Topping.

Comment: I figured out the search() method for owlready2. Hope this gives me an O(1) time complexity.

Comment: @gag123 Can you post your solution?